# How do I create a security timeout in ColdFusion?

Tags: security, coldfusion, timeout

I am creating an application that needs more advanced security measures, besides logging in with an account.

I want the whole website to track how long a user has been idle, and then automatically log them out after 30 seconds. So that their session expires, thus having them to log in again.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: use the `sessionTimeout` attribute in your Application file http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html

Comment: @MattBusche... any reason you didn't just make this an answer?

Comment: @AdamCameron because it was a one sentence answer and those are usually frowned upon, but I've made it an answer nonetheless

Comment: 30 seconds is very low. You may want to consider 30 minutes instead

Comment: @MattBusche, regarding one sentence answers, I was once taught that brevity was one of the features of effective communications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `sessionTimeout` attribute in your `Application` file. [Adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html)

Comment: This might be only part of the answer.  A js countdown that sends the user to a "you timed out" page may also be necessary.

Comment: @DanBracuk sure, but that was never mentioned anywhere in his question